# Git: How do download just a particular commit and not clone the rest of the repository?

Tags: git

I have a git repository and I want to just download the state of that repository at a  particular commit. How do I do that?

I don't intend to make any changes to the repository afterwards, and I don't need the .git folder as I do not want to download unnecessary files. I just want the code in a particular commit.

Is there a way to do that with git?

Comment: Why not just download the entire repository, check out the specific commit, and then delete the `.git` folder?

Comment: Takes longer! And saving bandwidth. Consider ppl on Raspberry pi's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone git repository with specific revision/changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset)

Comment: Not a dup! This is about not cloning the whole repo!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: get specific revision from remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472155/git-get-specific-revision-from-remote-server)

Comment: The closest you can get to doing this is to use [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) with the [`--remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#Documentation/git-archive.txt---remoteltrepogt) option, but as mentioned in the docs, it relies on specific repo configs to get it properly working with a plain sha1 of the commit. A workaround, would be to tag the commit, then depending on the server (Github, Gitlab), download a copy of the repo as a tar.gz using the tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shallow clone a specific commit with depth 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278902/how-to-shallow-clone-a-specific-commit-with-depth-1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+shallow+clone+specific+commit

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with recent enough git and it should be enabled on a server.

Here is how to fetch and checkout commit `71bbabb16755c3d611bb24909e77a0df688827aa` as local branch 'main' from https://github.com/curl/curl:

```
git init curl
cd curl
git fetch --depth=1 https://github.com/curl/curl 71bbabb16755c3d611bb24909e77a0df688827aa:refs/heads/main
git checkout main
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just download a particular commit. Instead of you can clone a specific branch from the remote repository and then switch to any commit.

Here is the syntax of the command to clone the specific git branch.

```
git clone -b <BRANCH_NAME> <GIT_REMOTE_URL>
```

You can use `--single-branch` to prevent fetching details of other branches like below:

```
git clone -b <BRANCH_NAME> --single-branch <GIT_REMOTE_URL>
```

If you go to the directory of your downloaded project and run the following command:

```
git branch -a
```

you can see the `.git` folder does not include information about other branches.

So now, fetch your desired commit by the following command:

```
git checkout <COMMIT_SHA1_KEY>
```

**Note:** You can clone only the latest commit from a given branch by using `--depth=n`

```
git clone -b <BRANCH_NAME> --single-branch --depth=2 <GIT_REMOTE_URL>
```